# Issues with feeding the data tables into tables when using many to many relation

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am developing an app which having two models, as I specified many to many relation therefore django creates 3rd table by itself to define the relation between two models but I am unable to feed the data(id's of both the table) in to this 3rd table.So anybody can tell me how can I do it

model.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Customer(models.Model):
    user        =models.OneToOneField(User)
    birthday    =models.DateField()
    website     =models.CharField(max_length=50)
    store       =models.CharField(max_length=50)
    welcomemail =models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
             return self.user

class Customer_check_attributes(models.Model):
    user        =models.ManyToManyField(User)
    billing_add =models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True , null=True)
    shipping_add    =models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True , null=True)
    payment_method  =models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True , null=True)
    shipping_method =models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True , null=True)
    reward_points   =models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True , null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to access the intermediate table? There's no reason to do so if you're just using the automatically-created one and you haven't added any extra fields on the relation.

Just add items to your many-to-many the usual way:

```
item1 = Model1.objects.create(foo='bar')
item2 = Model2.objects.create(spam='eggs')
item1.item2s.add(item2)
```

Comment: how can I use it can you please explain me this is my model `from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Customer(models.Model):
 user  =models.OneToOneField(User)
 birthday =models.DateField()
 website  =models.CharField(max_length=50)
 store  =models.CharField(max_length=50)
 welcomemail =models.CharField(max_length=50)

 def __unicode__(self):
             return self.user

class Customer_check_attributes(models.Model):
 user  =models.ManyToManyField(User)
 billing_add =models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True , null=True)

Comment: And what is your question now?

Comment: **sorry for late reply** Can you show me one example of many to many relation and there is anything extra needed to do in view.py when submitting the data